# Scrapy crawler acting weirdly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a script in python scrapy to parse different categories from craigslist. I noticed some weird things executing the script. It runs flawlessly leaving nothing to complaint. However, the thing is: if I leave `items.py` blank like below, it doesn't have any effect in the crawling process. My question is what is it doing in my scrapy project then? Thanks in advance.

"Items.py" file contains:

```
import scrapy

class CraigItem(scrapy.Item):
    pass
```

The spider contains:

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy import Request

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "category"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr"]

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')

        for job in jobs:
            relative_url = job.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
            title = job.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
            address = job.xpath('span[@class="result-meta"]/span[@class="result-hood"]/text()').extract_first("")[2:-1]   
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'URL': absolute_url, 'Title': title, 'Address':address})

        relative_next_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_url = "https://newyork.craigslist.org" + relative_next_url    
        yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        url = response.meta.get('URL')
        title = response.meta.get('Title')
        address = response.meta.get('Address')
        compensation = response.xpath('//p[@class="attrgroup"]/span[1]/b/text()').extract_first()
        employment_type = response.xpath('//p[@class="attrgroup"]/span[2]/b/text()').extract_first()
        yield{'URL': url, 'Title': title, 'Address':address, 'Compensation':compensation, 'Employment_Type':employment_type}
```

Again my question is: doesn't `items.py` file have any supervision in the crawling process? If it is, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [Scrapy Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) first. In short, Scrapy Items are dict-like classes that define items your spider produces. When you yield an item from spider, it has to be either Scrapy Item or a dict (or, a `Request` object). In your spider, you chose to use the second approach, i.e. yield plain dict.

The file `items.py` is a template produced by `scrapy startproject` command which defines blank Item class for you to enhance it, if you like. But as you don't use that class in your spider, it's not used by Scrapy.

Comment: Thanks Tomáš Linhart, for your answer. In fact, I kicked `items.py` out from scrapy project and ran again. I found it still working. That means,, it is not being used by Scrapy.

Comment: @Topto Sure, it's just a (almost) blank module, which is not imported anywhere.

Comment: Here is what I wanted to be sure about. Thanks a zillion  Tomáš Linhart. You made my day.